# Xcode UI tests for a framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have two apps between which I want to share a single view controller. The rest of the apps' UI is completely separate, but they'll share this one view controller with slight configuration differences.

I decided the best way to approach this was with a framework that can be added to both apps. My framework has its own storyboard which is connected up through storyboard references to each app.

I would like to be able to run Xcode UI tests on the framework. I'd like these tests to be a part of the framework project itself and not part of the UI tests for each of the apps that embed it. Is this possible? I can't figure out how to run UI tests on the framework without first embedding it in a controlling app.

Is there a way to embed the framework in an app for UI testing but have the UI tests as part of the framework project itself? Or would I have to have, say, a sample app included as part of a workspace, and the sample app contain all my UI tests?

Comment: "I can't figure out how to run UI tests on the framework without first embedding it in a controlling app." I can figure out what it would even _mean_ to run UI tests on a framework without first embedding it an controlling app. Even running UI tests on an _app_ requires that you first embed it an app.

Comment: @matt OK well maybe I'll rephrase to be more specific... is there a way to embed the framework in an app for UI testing but have the UI tests as part of the framework project itself? Or would I have to have, say, a sample app included as part of a workspace, and the sample app contains all my UI tests?

Comment: I can't imagine there would be any way to do that. When I add a framework _target_ to an existing app project, it can have accompanying unit tests, but not UI tests. And that makes sense, I think.

Comment: I'm loath to answer this, but someone (@matt) should really answer this. Going through comments is sub-optimal.